# How to change Application name on Mobile language change - Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, multilingual

I implemented Multilingual in my cordova based Mobile Application. On Mobile language change(lets say Spanish), My Application changes to Spanish. But the Application didn't found a way to change the Application name.

I got the device language in `onDeviceReady()` using `navigator.language`

With the device language, I am dynamically inserting the JavaScript values files.

```
if (ApplicationLanguage == 'es-ES' || ApplicationLanguage == 'es-US') {
        var jsfile = $("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/common/multilingual/values-es.js'>");
        $("head").append(jsfile);
    }
else {
    var jsfile = $("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/common/multilingual/values-en.js'>");
    $("head").append(jsfile);
}
```

This works as expected but how to change the **Application Name** to Spanish if the Mobile device language is Spanish.

Comment: you want to change the <title> tag of your cordova app?

Comment: the thing you can change with i18l is the title tag inside the body, not the one inside the head

Comment: Are you trying to change the app's name on the home screen?

Comment: Is there any option available in Cordova to specify the Application name with different languages and load the App name on App boot with respect to the device language ?